# Import Wireshark Cookies into Firefox?

Tags: authentication, web-application, network, penetration-test, cookies

I'm trying to copy session cookies (collected using Wireshark) into a different Firefox sessions. But can't seem to find a method or working add-on to manage the cookies.

[image]

Greasemonkey and tampermonkey's "cookie injector" userscripts don't seem to work. [Many other FF add-on's](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=cookies) either require JSON format, Netscape format (output formats Wireshark doesn't support) or the cookie add-on's don't feature the ability to import cookies at all.

**Is it currently possible to import cookies (collected using Wireshark) using Firefox?**

References:

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=wireshark+cookies
https://github.com/ihciah/cookieinjector
```

**UPDATE:**

[image]

It seems if there aren't cookies set already, I can't right-click on any of the parameters (Name, Path, Domain) to add data. Only if there are cookies already present it's possible to "Delete All" or "Add Item". Is there a solution for adding cookies using `Storage` when no cookies are present?

Comment: Does `document.cookie = "sessionId=dsajkhdslkj"` not work?

Comment: @Matthew thanks for your reply. I'm nor sure I follow. When I paste the copied cookie into a text files, its almost 1,000 characters and has several parameters (e.g., "_ud=","__rtgt_sid=", "d7s_uid=", "d7s_spc=") with encoded strings. How can I use this info with `document.cookie`?

Comment: Each of those parameters looks like it is a distinct cookie, so you'd just set them one by one.

Comment: Following your update: We need more information to understand whether the lack of cookies is normal. In your case, are you authenticated on this website? Is it the same website you retrieved the cookie using Wireshark?

Comment: If you visit [www.example.com](https://www.example.com/), you can see that no cookie has been created. Because the website doesn't need to. If you go on [www.google.com](https://www.google.com/), you can see that cookies have been created, even though you're not authenticated. It's probably for tracking purpose and other technical stuff. I don't know which website you visited in your example, but you probably were not authenticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Matthew](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/89876/matthew) said, you can directly set the cookies with the `document.cookies="..."` command in your browser console.

Example on [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com):

[image: Setting up the cookie]

As you can see, I am not logged in. I cheated a bit and directly retrieved my cookie through my browser, and not through wireshark, but your question is about setting it once retrieved.

```
Cookie Name  |  Value
acct         |  t=7c6483ddcd99eb112c060ecbe0543e86&s=080f651e3fcca17df3a47c2cecfcb880
```

To set it, you can use the `document.cookies="{COOKIE_NAME}={VALUE}"` command, like I did on the picture above. You need to repeat this command for any cookie you want to set.

I just need to refresh the page, and the cookie will authenticate me.

[image: I am logged in]

Here, the `Storage` tab shows the cookies that have been set.

Note that other security controls may be put in place to prevent cookie theft, like checking other information associated with the user. (Browser, IP, etc.) It is the case here, I couldn't do much before being deauthenticated.

Comment: thank you for this answer. It seems like my solution, but I'm having a small issue implementing it. See the updated question. @Yuriko